# OutOfMemoryException - is this a false alarm

Tags: exception, out-of-memory, windbg, sos

My dump file contains OutOfMemoryException but all the object fields seem to be null.  Is it just a false alarm or is there someway to know about this exception?

```
0:052> !do 000000027fff10e8 
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.18449
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.34011
Name:        System.OutOfMemoryException
MethodTable: 000007fcb5476920
EEClass:     000007fcb4f3cd88
Size:        160(0xa0) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fcb5476508  4000002        8        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _className
000007fcb547e880  4000003       10 ...ection.MethodBase  0 instance 0000000000000000 _exceptionMethod
000007fcb5476508  4000004       18        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _exceptionMethodString
000007fcb5476508  4000005       20        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _message
000007fcb547e238  4000006       28 ...tions.IDictionary  0 instance 0000000000000000 _data
000007fcb5476738  4000007       30     System.Exception  0 instance 0000000000000000 _innerException
000007fcb5476508  4000008       38        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _helpURL
000007fcb5476ae8  4000009       40        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _stackTrace
000007fcb5476ae8  400000a       48        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _watsonBuckets
000007fcb5476508  400000b       50        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _stackTraceString
000007fcb5476508  400000c       58        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _remoteStackTraceString
000007fcb54792b8  400000d       88         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _remoteStackIndex
000007fcb5476ae8  400000e       60        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _dynamicMethods
000007fcb54792b8  400000f       8c         System.Int32  1 instance      -2147024882 _HResult
000007fcb5476508  4000010       68        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _source
000007fcb547a338  4000011       78        System.IntPtr  1 instance                0 _xptrs
000007fcb54792b8  4000012       90         System.Int32  1 instance       -532462766 _xcode
000007fcb542cdd8  4000013       80       System.UIntPtr  1 instance                0 _ipForWatsonBuckets
000007fcb5499eb8  4000014       70 ...ializationManager  0 instance 0000000000000000 _safeSerializationManager
000007fcb5476ae8  4000001        0        System.Object  0   shared           static s_EDILock
                                 >> Domain:Value  0000000002b83fd0:NotInit  <<
```

Comment: Usually OutOfMemoryException is a collateral effect caused by an infinite loop, memory leak or something like that, but I'm not sure if is this the case. Can you give more specific details? Where is the code?

Comment: code base is huge, millions of lines. Plus I don't see any sign of memory usage going high. That's what make me thinking its a false alarm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One OutOfMemoryException object is pre-allocated by the framework when it starts up.  The existence of this object does not indicate a problem.  I think that this is what you are seeing.

Comment: Are there any such other exceptions objects that are pre-allocated and could be safely ignored?

Comment: @PaulSnow, Only when the exception might not be possible to allocate it in the event of that particular exception being throw is it pre-allocated. This is the case for [`ExecutionEngineException`, `StackOverflowException`, and `OutOfMemoryException`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/08/10/why-do-i-see-executionengineexception-stackoverflowexception-and-outofmemoryexception-on-the-heap-when-debugging-net-applications.aspx).